# heroku rake db:migrate didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've run a migration adding active column to users using heroku rake db:migrate.
and succesfully. but when I run the application the "active" column/attributes is not defined.

I already try to migrate:down and run migrate again for that version.. but it's still not worked.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not defined" ?

Answer (score 2):

did you add `:active` to the list of accessible attributes?

```
attr_accessible :active
```

failing that, sometimes you need to run `heroku rake db:restart`

and just finally, if it's still not working, run `heroku logs` and you will probably find something

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will run both the up and the down which will help you better analyze the situation. Also, there may be a problem in your migrations, if you post the code I should be able to asset further.

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to restart you application or drop database, if it doesnt contain valuable information.